# Confirming if this trigger will do as I intend

Tags: postgresql

I have been using Postgres for a while now, but I have not implemented any triggers yet. I wanted to check if this will do what I intend it to do.

On a daily basis, I am adding new rows to a table (COPY) and also updating existing rows if there is a primary key conflict (ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET). I then have a materialized view using that table and a few other joins, and this view is used for a lot of reporting.

I want the materialized view to update when the original table has been updated, without me needing to schedule it or run it manually. (Right now I have it scheduled with a Python psycopg2 execute command).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_mat_view()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW schema_name.materialized_view_name;
    RETURN NULL;
END $$;

CREATE TRIGGER refresh_view
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE OR TRUNCATE
ON sutherland.dimension_peoplesoft FOR EACH STATEMENT
EXECUTE PROCEDURE refresh_mat_view();
```

Would that refresh the view for every single row which is updated too? I am just imagining it trigger a refresh for each individual row which might be 100k+. It would be better to happen AFTER all inserts have been done (I have Python looping through each row in a pandas DataFrame to UPSERT into the database).

Comment: The code you show doesn't help. You can define your tables constraints as INITIALLY DEFERRED. Transaction demarcation also has an influence.

Answer (score 0):

When you use a pure Materialized View, every time you refresh it, it will rebuild the whole thing. So if your data changes a lot and you need the data available fast it's not an optimized choice.

You should use Eager Materialized Views or Lazy Materialized Views that basically are "A well use of triggers". Obviously it's harder to do than a pure materialized view, but the results are better (depending on the case of use).

You should check this article [Materialized View Strategies Using PostgreSQL](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/materialized-view-strategies-using-postgresql)